# Java Text File Encoding

Tags: java, encoding, character-encoding, text-files

I have a text file and it can be ANSI (with ISO-8859-2 charset), UTF-8, UCS-2 Big or Little Endian.

Is there any way to detect the encoding of the file to read it properly?

Or is it possible to read a file without giving the encoding? (and it reads the file as it is)

(There are several program that can detect and convert encoding/format of text files.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

UTF-8 and UCS-2/UTF-16 can be distinguished reasonably easily via a [byte order mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte-order_mark) at the start of the file. If this exists then it's a *pretty good bet* that the file is in that encoding - but it's not a dead certainty. You may well also find that the file *is* in one of those encodings, but doesn't have a byte order mark.

I don't know much about ISO-8859-2, but I wouldn't be surprised if almost *every* file is a valid text file in that encoding. The best you'll be able to do is check it heuristically. Indeed, the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-2) talking about it would suggest that only byte 0x7f is invalid.

There's no idea of reading a file "as it is" and yet getting text out - a file is a sequence of *bytes*, so you have to apply a character encoding in order to decode those bytes into characters.

Answer (score 11):

Yes, there's a number of methods to do character encoding detection, specifically in Java.  Take a look at [jchardet](http://jchardet.sourceforge.net/) which is based on the Mozilla algorithm.  There's also [cpdetector](http://cpdetector.sourceforge.net/) and a project by IBM called [ICU4j](http://site.icu-project.org/).  I'd take a look at the latter, as it seems to be more reliable than the other two.  They work based on statistical analysis of the binary file, ICU4j will also provide a confidence level of the character encoding it detects so you can use this in the case above.  It works pretty well.

Answer (score 4):

You can use ICU4J (http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4j/)

Here is my code:

```
            String charset = "ISO-8859-1"; //Default chartset, put whatever you want

            byte[] fileContent = null;
            FileInputStream fin = null;

            //create FileInputStream object
            fin = new FileInputStream(file.getPath());

            /*
             * Create byte array large enough to hold the content of the file.
             * Use File.length to determine size of the file in bytes.
             */
            fileContent = new byte[(int) file.length()];

            /*
             * To read content of the file in byte array, use
             * int read(byte[] byteArray) method of java FileInputStream class.
             *
             */
            fin.read(fileContent);

            byte[] data =  fileContent;

            CharsetDetector detector = new CharsetDetector();
            detector.setText(data);

            CharsetMatch cm = detector.detect();

            if (cm != null) {
                int confidence = cm.getConfidence();
                System.out.println("Encoding: " + cm.getName() + " - Confidence: " + confidence + "%");
                //Here you have the encode name and the confidence
                //In my case if the confidence is > 50 I return the encode, else I return the default value
                if (confidence > 50) {
                    charset = cm.getName();
                }
            }
```

Remember to put all the try catch need it.

I hope this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

If your text file is a properly created Unicode text file then the Byte Order Mark (BOM) should tell you all the information you need.  See [here](http://codesnipers.com/?q=node/68) for more details about BOM

If it's not then you'll have to use some encoding detection library.