# How to Identify the Encoding for a Text File

Tags: java, encoding, character-encoding

Someone suggested a HEX editor which I downloaded and ran. However looking at these lovely groups of numbers and letters I still don't know what encoding it is in.

The guy who emailed me the file told me it is microsoft. :)

Any ideas?

Thanks-in-Advance,

Guido

P.S. I tagged it Java because the code processing the file is in Java.

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:java]?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java : How to determine the correct charset encoding of a stream](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/499010/java-how-to-determine-the-correct-charset-encoding-of-a-stream), [How to reliably guess the encoding between MacRoman, CP1252, Latin1, UTF-8, and ASCII](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198804/), [Java Text File Encoding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1288899/) and more. See also "Related" column on right hand side (which is indeed exactly the same list as you saw (and ignored?) after entering the question's title).

Comment: @jli: I added a P.S. to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use http://www.textpad.com/ for this all the time.

Open the file and then go to 'Save as'...  You should be able to see the current encoding.

Comment: Notepad++ can also do encoding detection. Also on linux, see the `file` command: http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_file.htm

Comment: @Ben B: Got it. Thanks. UTF-16LE. TextPad didn't tell me that but it told me enough to figure out the rest.